# angular-translate not working but not errors

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

I've just installed angular-translate, but the webpage after this doesn't work.

Here you can find my code:

```
app.js

angular
.module('frontEndApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngStorage',
    'ngResource',
    'angular-translate'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'main'
        })
```

Index.html.

```
  <script src="bower_components/angular-translate/angular-translate.js"></script>
<!-- endbower -->
<!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
<script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/about.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/prueba/pruebaController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/loginController.js"></script>
<script src="scripts/controllers/department/departmentController.js"></script>
<script src="config/appConstants.js"></script>
<script src="config/languajes.js"></script>
```

languajes.js

```
'user strict';

var app = angular.module('frontEndApp', ['pascalprecht.translate']);

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        code: 'Code',
        department: 'Deparment',
        description: 'Description',
        boss: 'Boss',
        project: 'Project'
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('es', {
        code: 'Código',
        department: 'Deparmento',
        description: 'Descripción',
        boss: 'Jefe',
        project: 'Proyecto'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    // $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParamenters');
}]);

    app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

    app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
        $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
        $translate.use(key);
      };
    });
```

bower.json

```
 {
"name": "front-end",
"version": "0.0.0",
"dependencies": {
"angular": "^1.6.6",
"bootstrap-sass-official": "^3.2.0",
"angular-animate": "^1.6.6",
"angular-aria": "^1.6.6",
"angular-cookies": "^1.6.6",
"angular-messages": "^1.6.6",
"angular-resource": "^1.6.6",
"angular-route": "^1.6.6",
"angular-sanitize": "^1.6.6",
"angular-touch": "^1.6.6",
"bootstrap-sass": "bootstrap-sass-official#^3.3.7",
"ngstorage": "^0.3.11",
"angular-translate": "^2.16.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
"angular-mocks": "^1.6.6",
"angularLocalStorage": "ngStorage#^0.3.2"
},
"appPath": "app",
"moduleName": "frontEndApp",
"overrides": {
"bootstrap": {
  "main": [
    "less/bootstrap.less",
    "dist/css/bootstrap.css",
    "dist/js/bootstrap.js"
    ]
   }
 }
}
```

The problem is the system works fine, but when I insert the script

all is gone, the webpage is blank only the header appears.

I have tried several solutions but I have no idea.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=pascalprecht.translate

https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide

Answer (score 0):

In *languajes.js*:

`angular.module('frontEndApp', ['pascalprecht.translate'])`

is telling `angular` to create a module called `frontEndApp` - which overrides the module you've created in *app.js*.

(Overrides because *app.js* is run before *languajes.js* due to the order of the scripts in the HTML).

---

What you need to do:

*app.js*

```
angular
.module('frontEndApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngStorage',
    'ngResource',
    'pascalprecht.translate'
])
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'main'
        })
```

*languajes.js*

```
'user strict';

var app = angular.module('frontEndApp');

app.config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        code: 'Code',
        department: 'Deparment',
        description: 'Description',
        boss: 'Boss',
        project: 'Project'
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('es', {
        code: 'Código',
        department: 'Deparmento',
        description: 'Descripción',
        boss: 'Jefe',
        project: 'Proyecto'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    // $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParamenters');
}]);

app.config(['$locationProvider', function ($locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
}]);

app.controller('Ctrl', function ($scope, $translate) {
    $scope.changeLanguage = function (key) {
    $translate.use(key);
  };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution.
`use strict`;

```
/**
 * @ngdoc overview
 * @name frontEndApp
 * @description
 * # frontEndApp
 *
 * Main module of the application.
 */

angular
.module('frontEndApp', [
    'ngAnimate',
    'ngAria',
    'ngCookies',
    'ngMessages',
    'ngResource',
    'ngRoute',
    'ngSanitize',
    'ngTouch',
    'ngStorage',
    'ngResource',
    'pascalprecht.translate'
]).config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
            controller: 'MainCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'main'
        })
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl: 'views/about.html',
            controller: 'AboutCtrl',
            controllerAs: 'about'
        })
        .when('/prueba', {
            templateUrl: 'views/prueba/prueba.html',
            controller: 'pruebaController',
            controllerAs: 'prueba'
        })
        .when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'views/login/login.html',
            controller: 'loginController',
            controllerAs: 'login'
        })
        .when('/department', {
            templateUrl: 'views/department/department.html',
            controller: 'departmentController',
            controllerAs: 'departmentController',
            data: {
                title: 'department',
                section: 'department'
            }
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/'
        });
}).config(['$translateProvider', function ($translateProvider) {

    $translateProvider.translations('en', {
        code: 'Code',
        department: 'Deparment',
        description: 'Description',
        boss: 'Boss',
        project: 'Project'
    });

    $translateProvider.translations('es', {
        code: 'Código',
        department: 'Deparmento',
        description: 'Descripción',
        boss: 'Jefe',
        project: 'Proyecto'
    });

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en');
    // $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParamenters');
}]);
```